# CiviCRM 4.6.3 says no extensions available

Tags: civimail, 4.6.3, mandrill

I cannot update my Mandrill Transactional Emails extension (v 1.5) to version 2.0, because CiviCRM  won't list any extensions.

How can I install the update?  Extension documentation says that if I uninstall, all database records are removed for prior mailings. There's no documented "manual install" process, and as noted, it's not offering an update to version 2.0 of the extension.

I posted this on the Mandrill Transaction Email extension github (issue 86), and he said to post the question here because it appears to be a CiviCRM problem (my paraphrasing). https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.mte/issues/86

CiviCRM 4.6.3
Joomla 3.4.1
PHP 5.5.25
Linux

Although demo site (running 4.6.0) says there are extensions available, my site running 4.6.3 says "No Extensions Available"

[image]

Going to the link provided "requested extensions from here": (https://civicrm.org/extdir/ver=4.6.3|cms=Joomla) only leads to a second page with even more extensions. It **NEVER** actually downloads/opens any xml files. Clicking the link on that page just gets a "circular reference to a longer page of all extensions, which then doesn't do anything when clicked.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can do a manual upgrade by downloading and extracting the zip file for 2.0 branch on github and running the upgrade script, I think it's CRM/Mte/Upgrade/Upgrader.php.  I directed you here because the general problem of not showing any extension available is not related to the Mandrill extension, and it has cropped up for other domains recently. You might want to repost with that as the fovus of the questoon, rather than Mandrill extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can control which extensions are displayed by overriding $civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url']

try something like $civicrm_setting['Extension Preferences']['ext_repo_url'] = 'http://civicrm.org/extdir/ver={ver}|cms={uf}|status=';

obviously be careful that you install things that are compatible.

Comment: If I understand the comment, you're suggesting that I could "spoof" the system by requesting extensions for a different version of CiviCRM, correct? That's interesting, and I'll keep a note of it. I've responded to the JIRA issue now and will see how that goes first.

Comment: No, not really.  You can download any extension from the website.  This acts as a variable filter that controlls which extensions are installable vis the ui.  You may want to change this to allow betas on a dev machine for example.

Comment: The advantage to doing it this way is that when a new version is available it will show the update in the ui.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in CiviCRM 4.6.3, you need to upgrade to 4.6.4+: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16590

Comment: Thanks for the JIRA link. Although they say it's fixed, it still has same message/problem in Joomla for CiviCRM 4.6.4, so it's not fixed on my site at least. I'll try adding a comment to the JIRA issue. So, not sure if I should mark answer as "fixed", although answer is spot on the correct issue.

Comment: Is the message the exact same?  Look at Rares P's comments on the ticket to see if they apply to you.  Also try clearing cache, deleting templates_c, etc.